# Wrong time format ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepickermodetime

I have a time picker which displays time in 12 Hour format. Internally i am converting it to 24 Hour format. The problem is, if the time taken is 10:24, it displays 10:01. i.e 'now' will have 10:24 and 'self.currentTime' will have 10:01. What am i doing wrong.

```
NSDate *now = [timePicker date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:MM:SS";
self.currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"The Current Time is %@",self.currentTime);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please read the documentation about the proper format specifiers.

Comment: Why is there a time difference of 13 minutes between the two variables? lol weird

Comment: @Pavan You mean 23 minutes? See the answer for the reason. The `01` is the month, not the minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MM` is "month of year", not "minute". You also want "s" (for seconds) rather than "S" (for fractions of a second).

I suspect you want a format of `HH:mm:ss`.

See the ["date formatters" documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) for more inforamtion - in particular, [UTS 35, tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the most recent version of iOS.